# Bypass mutating trigger in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle11g, oracle-apex

I have two tables; on update of table 1 (cars bought), I need to update the other table with the sum of total cars bought by a specific customer.

When I try it, I encountered a mutating trigger. I have tried to convert it to a compound trigger, however I am encountered a vast number of errors, null index etc.

detail_table:

```
+-----------+---------+--------+------+------+
| customore | car     | number | cost | sold |
+-----------+---------+--------+------+------+
| josh      | mustang | 2      | 5    | y    |
| josh      | ford    | 3      | 2    | y    |
| josh      | tesla   | 1      | 3    | n    | -->to update to y
| john      | chevy   | 4      | 1    | y    |
| john      | chevy   | 5      | 2    | y    |
+-----------+---------+--------+------+------+
```

On update of sold from n to y, the rows must roll up and sum into this summary table

summary_table

```
  +----------+------------+------------+
  | customer | total cars | total cost | 
  +----------+------------+------------+
  | josh     | 5          | 7          | -- > before update  on detail
  +----------+------------+------------+

  +----------+------------+------------+
  | customer | total cars | total cost | 
  +----------+------------+------------+
  | josh     | 6          | 10         | -- > after update on detail
  +----------+------------+------------+
```

In the end when the user updates n to y for josh.total cars supposed to become 1 and total cost 10

trigger code

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER update_summary_table
    AFTER UPDATE ON detail_table FOR EACH ROW 
    referencing old as old new as new
begin
    
     for i in (select sum(number) s_car, sum(cost) s_cost
               from detail_table 
               where  customer = :new.customer
                 and sold = 'y') loop

update summary_table
set total_cars = i.s_car,
   total_cost = i.s_cost
where customer = :new.customer;

end loop;
end;
end update_summary_table;
```

Comment: Please let me know if you need further details like my code etc

Comment: A mutating table error indicates you are trying to process the table that caused the trigger to fire. This is **not allowed** (at least most instances). It also  is typically a sign of poor design, but can also be just improper code. Which cannot be determined withe the code itself. Please post the trigger itself.

Comment: ok let me re edit the above including the code

Comment: the trigger is there, it will mutate because of the action im performing, i know.. i just want to know how i get around it because this update news to be done to the customer  (s) who have been updated to y at that specific time. I could have done an after statement trigger but that would have updated every customer record within the summary table.. not something i would like to happen. please help mate. not too keen on triggers. its not aprt of me job. this really important please

Comment: I would submit that your fundamental design of the summary table is flawed.  Any time you store a value that can be calculated, you run a very high risk of that value getting 'out of synch'.  In fact I'd say it's only a matter of time.  Instead of trying to store 'total cars' and 'total cost', you should simply compute them from the detail table _when you need to report them_.  Tables should be designed to principles of data normalization - Third Normal Form, not to map 1:1 to the needs of some report.

Comment: @EdStevens this was the approach i wanted to take but requirements made it mandatory for me to use the submitted structure. Its wierd i know but... just the way it is rn ...sadly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why would you use a `for` loop for this?  Just use a single update:

```
update summary_table
    set total_cars = coalesce(total_cars, 0) + :new.number - :old.number,
        total_cost = coalesce(total_cost, 0) + :new.cost - :old.cost
    where customer = :new.customer;
```

This does an *incremental* change to the summary rather than entirely recalculating the row.

The use of `coalesce()` is just in case no default value is given for new rows.

Comment: @gordon linoff, May you please share what is the significance of Old.number and old.cost here?

Comment: @AnkitBajpai . . . I thought the answer explained that.  This is changing the totals *incrementally*, subtracting off the old value and adding in the new one.

Comment: Apologies but I still didn't get it. In the above example, New.number is 1 and old.number is 5. So for total_cars this would ended up becoming as 1 instead of 6.

Comment: @AnkitBajpai . . . The difference is added to the existing value.

Comment: @GordonLinoff  I began to test the code today, i believe that the math is off as ankit explained.  example - if i had number of cars currently  5 + 1 - 5 then i would end up with 1 -- subsequently if someone changed y to n for any of the previous transactions i would end up with numbers outa control.  i will work on the math a bit -- also negative numbers arent avoided here i think

Comment: @JayKhan . . . This modifies the existing value by adding in the new value and subtracting the old value.  That seems like the right match for keeping the summary up-to-date.  If the value is "5" and you change a row from "3" to "4", the new value is 5 - 3 + 4 = 6.  That is correct math.